# Another evening, another meta-tag: 'alternative'

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

[alternative](/questions/tagged/alternative) seems to be a great way to find shopping questions.

There are over 300. Should we attempt to close them out, or just call Trogdor on the tag?

Answer (score 3):

I would rather close the questions that need to be closed. Once the tag is burninated, there is no track of it, and it is not possible to know which questions had it.

Actually, not all the questions using that tag are shopping questions; there are questions that are about alternative methods for doing something (or alternative code to use). For sure, there are some questions that are not so good, and that could be closed, even if they are not shopping questions.

Once the questions to close are closed, the tag can be burninated.

Comment: Yeah, in this case it's probably a good idea to find the few 'gems' that should actually remain and remove the tag from them as you polish them up a bit. Whatever's left can be closed in short order and the tag can be banished to the outer realm.

Answer (score 2):

Please note, before burninating this tag, that it has a [valid use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13080606/157360) in reference to something specifically named `Alternative`, which is defined in [Haskell's core library](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#g:2)--"core" in the sense that versions of this library are inextricably tied to a specific compiler version, despite being treated as a regular library most of the time.

That said, there appear to be only two questions with both [alternative](/questions/tagged/alternative) and [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell) so the utility of the tag is minimal.

Comment: In that case, it should be called `haskell-alternative` or something.